# Slow console.log vs echo and fibonacci calculation nodejs vs php?

Tags: php, node.js

I make a benchmark nodejs vs php

Code PHP :

```
<?php
$start = microtime(true);
$x = 0;
$y = 1;

for($i=0;$i<=1000;$i++)
{
    $z = $x + $y;
    echo $z."\n";
    $x=$y;
    $y=$z;
}
$end = microtime(true);
echo "Time end ".(($end-$start)*1000)."\n";
```

Code Nodejs :

```
'use strict';
console.time('fibo');
let x = 0,y = 1;

for(let i=0;i<=1000;i++)
{
    let z = x + y;
    console.log(z);
    x = y;
    y = z;
}
console.timeEnd('fibo');
```

I test with nodejs 4.1.0,php 7 and php 5.5

Nodejs : 27 ms
PHP 5 : 20ms
PHP 7 : 1 - 4.5ms

#### Note 1:

I try remove echo and console.log nodejs 1ms, php 0,08ms ..

Anyone explain why nodejs run so slowly ?

Comment: If I comment out the `console.log(z)` call the node.js time goes to 0ms.

Comment: Outputting takes a significant amount of time. Remove them and try again.

Comment: remove echo and console.log will have same result, no echo PHP run with 0.08 ms but node run 1ms

Comment: So you are going to decide which technology to use because one can complete a trivial task 5 milliseconds faster than the other?

Comment: this question not for decide anything, I try benchmark nodejs vs php . I not sure php auto run multi core ?